# How can I set the value of new record's field on a subform?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form called `Assembly` that has a subform called `PartsList`. They are tied together with a field called `Parent`. They work off the same table, the main `Assembly` form just filters the `PartsList` subform via a combobox so that you only see records (`Child` field) on the subform with the same value for `Parent`.

I would like to use the subform to easily add children for the same `Parent`.

I have tried adding expressions and methods to the `BeforeInsert` property of the subform that attempts to set the value of the new record's `Parent` field to the current value of `Parent` in the main form.

```
BeforeInsert: =[Parent] = [Forms]![Assembly]![Parent]
```

I get an error:

> **An error occurred while referencing the object.** You tried to run a Visual Basic procedure that improperly references a property or method of an object.

And in VBA...

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    [Parent] = [Forms]![Assembly]![Parent]
End Sub
```

I get an error:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

I'm guessing my problems are that when I try to set the `[Parent]` field of the new record, I'm accessing the whole Parent field object and not just the value of the new record. I'm at a loss for how to get to just the value of the new record though.

EDIT:
I have also tried setting the default value for `Parent` on the subform to the current value of `Parent` on the main form, but the subform value doesn't update if I change the main form value.

Comment: Use another name than Parent, as this the name of the parent _object_.

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA place something like this.  This will trigger after each insert is complete and update the inserted records Parent field = current Parent field in the form.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert() 
   DoCMD.RunSQL "Update Assembly SET Parent = " & [Forms]![Assembly]![Parent]
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the Parent-Child in my table pair forms the key for the table. So I need to set the `Parent` value before insertion. Is there a way to edit the INSERT INTO statement that I assume Access runs when a new record is created?

Comment: Also the above command updates all the records under the parent field. Not just the new record.

Comment: Check out adjusting what Gustav recommended.  The vba code you posted is throwing the error because of how you're referencing Parent.  Try referencing it directly using Forms!PartsList!Parent = Forms!Assembly!Parent